# Reading from keyboard without pressing "enter" using JCurses

Tags: java, io, console, character, jcurses

I am writing an application that requires me to read a key from console without having to wait for the user to hit enter. I have read that JCurses library could help.

I tried using `Toolkit.readCharacter()` like this:

```
InputChar c = Toolkit.readCharacter();
system.out.println(c.getCharacter());
```

But the problem was that the `readCharacter()` method does not end execution no matter how many characters you input. Even if you press enter, it still seems that it is waiting for you to enter a character.

I really appreciate any help using JCurses, or any other way would do.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Java Curses has a couple of specific keystroke recognition methods, but tying yourself down to an external library for a single function may not be the best solution.

What you are after could be achieved by creating a terminal-style Swing application, and using a `KeyListener` to detect keystroke events. However, MadProgrammer notes in [How to make esc stop a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078336/how-to-make-esc-stop-a-method/17078531#17078531) that such a solution may have "focus issues".

So if you want to trace specific keystrokes, or want to affect program behaviour based on different user inputs, I would recommend using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#eg) which are implemented as part of Swing.

e.g.

```
component.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put
    (KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"),"actionName");
component.getActionMap().put("actionName", yourAction);
```

Where component is any `JComponent` object (assumably a terminal display), and `yourAction` is any Swing action. Using the paramaterised form of `getInputMap()` as shown here is preferable for a "console" application, as the user will necessarily making keystrokes within the top level window, and therefore component focus is irrelevant.

Comment: i don't think he's referring to Swing / AWT.  This is completely a JCurses(sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/‎) issue.

Comment: @GaryTsui The question states that "any other way would do". I agree that JCurses could be used, but I don't think that using an external library to implement a single piece of functionality is the best solution. Especially when the same can be achieved using native functions.

Answer (score 0):

This program worked for me.
You need to call ***Toolkit.init()*** to put the terminal into cbreak() mode.
And remember to call ***Toolkit.shutdown()*** before exiting.

A couple of drawbacks.

- jcurses automatically puts the tty into cbreak mode, and jcurses does not provide a method for manipulating the curses library directly.
- once you are in jcurses, the output is in cbreak mode and direct strings from java have newlines, but no carriage returns.
- the developers of jcurses only implemented the curses part of owning the whole screen.  jcurses seems overkill if all you want is cbreak mode.

The program.

```
import jcurses.system.CharColor;
import jcurses.system.InputChar;
import jcurses.system.Toolkit;

public class itest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int y = 0;
        CharColor color = new CharColor(CharColor.BLACK, CharColor.WHITE);
        Toolkit.init();
        while (true) {
            InputChar c = Toolkit.readCharacter();
            if ('q' == c.getCharacter())
                break;
            Toolkit.printString(String.format("c : %c", c.getCharacter()), 0, y++, color);
        }
        Toolkit.shutdown();
    }
}
```